# Calabi-Yau with nodes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a singular projective irreducible complex variety of dimension 3, and its singular loci are finite number of nodes, and its smooth locus $X_1$ is a Calabi-Yau quasi-projective variety, I have the following two questions

1. generally is $X$ a normal variety? Since the node has codimension 3, these singularities are very mild.
2. the canonical sheaf of $X_1$, $\omega_{X_1}$ is trivial since $X_1$ is Calabi-Yau, is the dualizing sheaf of $X$, $\omega_X$ trivial? i.e. $\mathscr{O}_X \cong \omega_X$?

Comment: Yes to both questions. A node in dimension $\ge 2$ is a normal Gorenstein singularity, this implies that $X$ is normal and $\omega _X=i_*\omega _{X_1}=\mathcal{O}_X$, where $i$ is the embedding of $X_1$ in $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am a physicist and don't know much about singularity theory! So is there any reference showing that a node of codimension greater than or equal to 2 is a normal Gorenstein singularity?

Comment: A hypersurface singularity is always Gorenstein, and it is normal as soon as it is of codimension at least $2$.

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi Thank you! Do you know any references about this?